# Data Masking in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, data-masking

I wanted to know is there any way we can achieve the below usecase from elasticsearch inbuild feature.

I have employee data indexed in elasticsearch search

> EMP ID    FNAME   LNAME   COUNTRY     Organization        Other 50 Attributes
>   associated with Employee
>
> 1 Jayesh  Bhoyar  United States   ABC
>
> 2 Tapan   pal United States   ABC
>
> 3 Ajay        United States   ABC
>
> 4 Ravi    Verma   Korea       ABC
>
> 7 Pankaj  Pal Korea       ABC
>
> 5 Sundar  Lal Japan       ABC
>
> 6 rahul   Sri Japan       ABC

Now we have 4 users and their access level:

User1 - has access to USA

User2 - has access to USA, Japan

User3 - has access to USA, Korea

User4 - has access to USA, Japan, Korea

**User 1**

> Now when User 1 search ABC he should get 7 results but output should
>   be as follows:
>
> EMP ID    FNAME   LNAME   COUNTRY     Organization        Other 50 Attributes
>   associated with Employee
>
> 1 Jayesh  Bhoyar  United States   ABC
>
> 2 Tapan   pal United States   ABC
>
> 3 Ajay        United States   ABC
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Korea       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Korea       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Japan       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Japan       XXX XXXXXXXX

**User2**

> Now when User 2 search ABC he should get 7 results but output should
>   be as follows:
>
> He should be able to see the Japan results and korean results should
>   be masked
>
> EMP ID    FNAME   LNAME   COUNTRY     Organization        Other 50 Attributes
>   associated with Employee
>
> 1 Jayesh  Bhoyar  United States   ABC
>
> 2 Tapan   pal United States   ABC
>
> 3 Ajay        United States   ABC
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Korea       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Korea       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> 5 Sundar  Lal Japan       ABC
>
> 6 rahul   Sri Japan       ABC

**User3**

> Now when User 3 search ABC he should get 7 results but output should
>   be as follows:
>
> He should be able to see the Korean results and Japan results should
>   be masked
>
> EMP ID    FNAME   LNAME   COUNTRY     Organization        Other 50 Attributes
>   associated with Employee
>
> 1 Jayesh  Bhoyar  United States   ABC
>
> 2 Tapan   pal United States   ABC
>
> 3 Ajay        United States   ABC
>
> 4 Ravi    Verma   Korea       ABC
>
> 7 Pankaj  Pal Korea       ABC
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Japan       XXX XXXXXXXX
>
> XXX   XXX XXX Japan       XXX XXXXXXXX

Is there any way we can achieve this by script or span or something else which is inbuild in elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's something you should perform on your backend not elasticsearch. The first step is you get permission data, and the second step you build a query with a filter that depends on the first step.